# Increment numeric pattern in file

Tags: sed, awk

I have a File that contains only the following line:

```
BOF
(REF-REQ0001 SW_requirement)
EOF
```

I need to generate a second file that would contain the following:

```
BOF
(REF-REQ0001 SW_requirement)
(REF-REQ0002 SW_requirement)
(REF-REQ0003 SW_requirement)
EOF
```

That is, the first line must be duplicated and for each of them the numeric part of "REQ0001" must be incremented with 1.

Comment: How many duplications? Does the first file always have 0001?

Comment: 4096 lines. That is, from REQ0001 to REQ4096. Yes, the first is always 0001.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of the first file (eg do you want to create multiple 4096-line files)? If so then what are the changing parts (eg are the literal strings BOF and EOF part of the file?) With your current formulation it's hard to understand why you need the first file and what it's a template for.

Answer (score 3):

perl would be good for this:

```
perl -ne 'for $n (1..4096) {s/\d+/ sprintf "%04d", $n /e; print}' File > File2
```

Comment: That works also, and already solves the second question raised after the answer of jimmij (perl print until the end of the line). Thank you both.

Comment: @glennjackman This repeats the each lines 4096 times.

Comment: true, but we're going on the OP's statement that the original file has one line.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if `BOF` and `EOF` are parts of the file, but anyhow you can try the following `awk` code:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="REQ| "}/[[:digit:]]/{for(i=0;i<4096;i++){printf($1"REQ%04d "$3"\n",$2+i)};next}1'
```

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks. Now, if after "SW_requirement" there are N additional words/columns, i.e. (REF-REQ0001 Column1 Column2 Column3 ColumnN), how can I print the whole line without calling word by word, i.e. printf($1"DLH%04d "$3" " $4"\n",$2+i)

Answer (score 1):

This prints the whole line by substituting a new value for field 2 and should work regardless of how many fields may appear later in the line.

```
awk -F 'REQ| ' '$1 == "(REF-" {field1 = $1; $1 = ""; num = $2; for (i = 0; i < 4096; i++) {$2 = sprintf("%sREQ%04d", field1, num + i); line = $0; sub("^ ", "", line); print line}; next} {print}' inputfile
```

Broken out on multiple lines:

```
awk -F 'REQ| ' '$1 == "(REF-" {
        field1 = $1; 
        $1 = ""; 
        num = $2; 
        for (i = 0; i < 4096; i++) {
            $2 = sprintf("%sREQ%04d", field1, num + i); 
            line = $0; 
            sub("^ ", "", line); 
            print line
        };
        next
    }
    {
        print
    }' inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

The following just uses `nl` mainly, though `tr` gens a bunch of blank lines and `sed` prepends the `REQ` bit...

```
IFS=\  read -r l r <file
tr \\0 \\n </dev/zero| 
nl -ba -w4 -nrz -s" $r"|
sed "s/^/${l%Q*}Q/;4096q"
```

First it saves the two halves in `$l` and `$r` with `read`. Then it `tr`anslates 4096 nuls into `\n`ewlines - which `nl` counts and appends `$r` to, and last `sed` just prepends `$l` to every one of its first 4096 input lines before `q`uitting input altogether.

Or far more simply w/ `seq`:

```
IFS=\  read -r l r <file
seq -ws " $r
${l%Q*}Q" 0 4097 | 
sed '1d;$d'
```